# Selenium, chromedriver and python difficulties

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, driver

I have this written down in my code but this keeps happening and I'm unsure what to do. I followed this video but don't know where to go as I followed the steps

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7R5n0sNSza8

> > > from selenium import webdriver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Comment: If you are really following that video step by step, what was the output you got when you did `python3 -m pip install selenium`?

Comment: Hey, so I found out what was wrong. Apparently when I first installed selenium I was on a different terminal thing. I was on bash instead of zsh and since I changed it and refollowed the step I got it to work. Thank you for your help!